# Using Paramiko to execute zfs commands on a remote file server completely hoses NFS/zfs for all users

Tags: python, python-2.7, filesystems, paramiko, zfs

I made a two-line change of code yesterday regarding Paramiko that should not (in so far as I can tell) have had any adverse effect, and immediately our phones started ringing and e-mails came in of reports of users unable to access to their NFS mounted home directories which are zfs filesystems.  I asked my colleagues for their opinion and everyone is stumped regarding why this change would have not only failed to accomplish what I set out to do, but also why it went so far as to hose everything for everybody.

After using Paramiko to execute a "zfs create" command to create a new user's NFS home directory, I was using a "time.sleep(5)" line of Python to give the remote system a chance to execute and process the command (sometimes particularly if the NFS server is under stress, it can take a second or two for the command to actually take effect).

Turns out, we seem to have hit a rare case where a 5 second delay wasn't enough.  So I decided to instead change it from a Python "time.sleep(5)" function, to instead use Paramiko's "channel.recv_exit_status()" function to wait for an exit status code, that way the amount of time taken is however much is required (not some arbitrary number of seconds).

Here's the difference in code (excised to reduce mundane stuff like determining zfs paths and usernames, etc.):

**ORIGINAL VERSION**:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("homedirserver.example.com")

# Create zfs share
command = "zfs create {0}/{1}".format(zfs_parent, username)
ssh.exec_command(command)

time.sleep(5)

# Confirm creation (this can fail without a time.sleep delay above)
command = "zfs list -H {0}/{1}".format(zfs_parent, username)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
error = stderr.read().strip()
if error != "":
    # log error, raise RuntimeError
```

**NEW VERSION**:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("homedirserver.example.com")

# Create zfs share
command = "zfs create {0}/{1}".format(zfs_parent, username)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)  # <--- CHANGED
status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()          # <--- NEW

# Confirm creation
command = "zfs list -H {0}/{1}".format(zfs_parent, username)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
error = stderr.read().strip()
if error != "":
    # log error, raise RuntimeError
```

It seems that when doing this, the "zfs create" command exists as a process on the file server and never completes.  `ps -eaf | grep "zfs create"` shows the command as a process on the file server that exists until I Ctrl+C out of the original calling program.  What is most surprising is it seems that this is enough to completely screw up all zfs filesystems which are exported from that server.  After Ctrl+C and waiting a couple of minutes, everything returned to business as usual and people stopped reporting the NFS outage.

This is with **Paramiko 1.14.1** and **Python 2.7.8**.  The executing/calling machine is **Solaris 11.2** and the remote file server (where the process hangs) is **Solaris 11.1**.

Comment: You do `ssh.exec_command(command)` twice. Is that intended?

Comment: @tdelaney Nope, not intended, that's a typo in my post :)  Fixing now.

Comment: You realize that by storing the stdin, stdout and stderr handles, but not reading from them, you're potentially letting output from the command block (if the command emits more output than the buffer has room for)? If you're going to store the handles, read from them *before* you wait for the process to exit. (And reading from them synchronously one at a time can lead to race conditions too, if they're both written to in a different order than the order you read in).

Comment: On a different note, it's better practice to check whether exit status is nonzero than to check whether stderr is nonempty; nonfatal warnings can be emitted to stderr, whereas the exit status is authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to do this in a safer way:

```
import pipes
command = "zfs create {0}/{1}".format(pipes.quote(zfs_parent), pipes.quote(username))
ssh.set_combine_stderr(True)
stdin, stdout, _ = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdin.close()
stdout_text = stdout.read()
status = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
```

The differences:

- We're explicitly closing stdin, so it's not possible for the process to block on it.
- We're telling paramiko we don't want stderr to be maintained separately; stderr content will instead be redirected to stdout. (This reduces some corner cases around read and write ordering; if you need to track this content and don't have ordering / length guarantees, things need to be more interesting).
- We're also trying to protect against malicious attacks resulting in code execution on the remote server, such as usernames containing `$(rm -rf /)`, by using `pipes.quote()`.

To be completely sure as to what's going on, of course, you'd want to use something like sysdig to monitor what's going on your ZFS server during operation (if my hypothesis above is correct, you'd see the tool blocked on write to stdout or stderr after interacting with the kernel enough to interrupt the filesystem's availability), but if you don't have a non-production environment for testing that might be a little uncomfortable to do.